# Is it possible to pass locals through a partial into another partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

This is an example to illustrate the question:

#### app/views/posts/show.html.haml

```
.post
  = render partial: 'avatar', locals: { user: @post.user }
  = @post.title
```

#### app/views/shared/_avatar.html.haml

```
.avatar
  = render partial: 'avatar_image', locals: { user: user }
  = user.name
```

#### app/views/shared/_avatar_image.html.haml

```
= image_tag user.image.url
```

Passing the locals received by partial `_avatar.html.haml` on to partial `_avatar_image.html.haml` would eliminate the need to repeat the locals (here: `{ user: user }`).

I know, I could use instance variables. But I would like to know if there is a way to generically pass all locals received to a underlying partial.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can use `local_assigns` to access the locals hash passed to your partial

```
.avatar
  = render partial: 'avatar_image', locals: local_assigns
  = user.name
```

Comment: For Rails >= 5.2 (at least), the answer seems to be `render partial: 'avatar_image', local_assigns` (the difference being no `locals` key).

Answer (score 0):

You can use instance variables, they are usually defined in the Controller's action and is shared between the action, the view and all the partial used.

## Instance variables:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @user = @post.user
end

# /posts/show.html.haml
.post
  = render partial: 'avatar', locals: { user: @post.user }
  = @post.title

# /shared/_avatar.html.haml
.avatar
  = render partial: 'avatar_image'
  = @user.name

# /shared/_avatar_image.html.haml
= image_tag @user.image.url
```

---

## Local variables:

You can't automatically pass the local variables to all related partial views (if so, then it would be the same as instance variables).

You need to do it manually, to 'filter' which variable is needed for each partial:

```
# /posts/show.html.haml
.post
  = render partial: 'avatar', locals: { user: @post.user }
  = @post.title

# /shared/_avatar.html.haml
.avatar
  = image_tag user.image.url
  = user.name
# This partial only needs a `User` instance, nothing else
```